# Mirth postprocessor

Tags: sql, postgresql, mirth

I have a channel, which has a reader configured to execute a SQL request every 5 seconds, and insert a new row in another table.

The table where it will insert data into:

```
CREATE TABLE timings(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    type TEXT NOT NULL,
    time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

The request in the postprocessor:

```
INSERT INTO timings (type, time) VALUES (${name}, NOW());
```

`${name}` is coming from the main SQL request.

After the request has been performed (the one that will generate a message), it executes the postprocessor request, even though there is nothing being output from the request. Is there a way to run the postprocessor script only when the SQL request returns something?

Also, it is using the last update name every 5 seconds, even though there was no data being generated. The weird thing is that it uses the last update name (`${name}`) for all the new `INSERT`s, resulting in lots and lots of rows containing the same data (except for the `time` column). Is that normal?

I'm using PostgreSQL as the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

The post processor is executed everytime a message is run through all destinations. If you want to execute your request only if the destination was successfull, then use a response transfomer. They located in the channel tasks beneath the transformer.
There you can use the responseStatus.

```
    if (responseStatus == SENT) {
// do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the post processor is not where I would do my db writes.  A simple destination would work fine.  Then you can put a filter for an empty "name" on the source.